# Automatic language detection by browser

Tags: grails, internationalization

How can I detect the language of the browser and automatically display the correctly localized version of my grails website depending on that value.

I put  this in to Index action

```
Locale locale = new Locale(params.lang)
cookieLocaleResolver.setLocale(request, response, (Locale)
session.getAttribute('locale'))
{  
    render controller: "home", action: "index"
    return             
}
```

And I got exception--

```
Error 500: Executing action [index] of controller [socialworking.HomeController] caused exception: null
Servlet: grails
URI: /socialworking/grails/home.dispatch
Exception Message:
Caused by:
Class: Unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should put that in a filter in grails-app/conf directory. Create a filter if you don't already have one.

MyFilters.groovy

```
class MyFilters {
    def filters = {
           setLocale(controller:'*', action:'*') {
                 before = {
                       // Your logic here
                 }
           }
    }
}
```

*Your logic here* could look in many ways, but here is a try:

```
String langToSet = 'en';
if ( params.lang && params.lang in validLanguages ) 
     langToSet = params.lang;
else if ( session.lang ) {
     langToSet = session.lang;
}
else if ( ...  ) // Cookie lang is set ( User might have accessed the site before and you have stored their preferred lang )
    // Get cookie lang

Locale locale = new Locale( langToUse)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, locale);

// Set the cookie lang
...
// We set the session lang
session.lang = langToSet
```

Note that the above is not a complete implementation but it is almost. The *cookie stuff* and *validLanguages* you should be able to figure out what they do.

I hope that helps!